# How to host Git server?

Tags: git, tfs

I am a total newbie to Git. All these years I have been using Team Foundation and its repository. With team foundation, you have a server that acts as central repository. This server is published as a site hosted on IIS so that you can do check-in and check-outs using the url of the TFS server . e.g. http://mytfs.com

I am searching for same option for Git. i.e. to host Git on a server that acts as a central repository. With Git I understand that check-in and check-out is replaced with pull and commit. I downloaded Git from https://git-scm.com/ and installed it on a server in the network but I am not able to figure out how to host it, how to configure user accounts etc. which you could do easily with TFS. There is no GUI or utility to manage the server. All I see is a installtion folder in the "C:\Program Files...". I have googled on this but I only find posts on creating branches, pulling and committing etc. I have also found some sites that publish a URL from where you can fork out the code. I want to create something similar.

Comment: Create an account on github and follow their tutorials to create a toy project hosted on github.  You can then learn from that.  When you know more, you are better equipped to understand what you need to do there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you added the TFS 2013 tag. TFS ships with a built-in git server which you can choose when you create a new Team Project. With TFS 2015 it became possible to host a TFVC and Git repository side-by-side in the same Team project. If you're on TFS 2013, the only way to get a Git repositories is to create a new project and select "Git" as the version control option. If you already have a TFS server setup, then this is 5 clicks (I'm guessing) away from having a git repository on your TFS server without having to install or really learn anything new.

Check out the announcement for Git under TFS 2013:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/11/13/git-for-tfs-2013/

And the current Git docs for TFS 2017 and Visual Studio Team Services:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/overview

It's now also relatively easy to import a TFS server into Visual Studio Team Services account. That way you'll always be up-to-date and will get early access to the newest features. Even if migrating to VS Team Services is no option, I highly recommend moving to TFS 2015u3 or 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, Git is a distributed protocol, so by design there is no such thing as a central repository. What one can do it bless a certain instance as being the central one for your organisation, but that is not a required feature, or one implemented by default.

There are a number of services that can offer a web style interface, Atlassian Bit Bucket Server, Github, Redmine and cgit are ones that spring to mind immediately

Comment: GitLab, Visual Studio Team Services as well.

Answer (score 1):

GIT is good for source control, but not for authentication/authorization.

You could `git init` on a remote mapped drive, and make use of file permissions to determine access to repositories. Then on a local machine clone from the network path. Eg. `git clone /n/myrepo/ /c/myrepo_local/`

If your looking for more sophisticated authentication, authorization, UI and dashboard etc. Your best bet is to look at bitbucket.com, github.com or gitlab.com (some of these also do on-prem but I believe you have to pay for that).

Also this is a really good tutorial from github.

https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

For web hosting I suggest Gerrit (for code review) https://www.gerritcodereview.com/ and GitWeb, https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb but there are other good alternatives.